# Any gem or plugin for sync data between server and mobile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make sure mobile and server use same data.  I used uuid to make sure each entry is unique but I want to know whether there is a gem to help merge data.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I just wanted to point out that there's two gems out there for syncing database and files between development and production in Rails:

Carr's [Data Sync](https://github.com/carr/data_sync)

and

Infinum's [Data Sync](https://github.com/infinum/data_sync)

The second one can be used with `gem 'data_sync'`, the first needs to be installed as a plugin.